# how to inherit classes in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote few css classes such as these:

```
.bad
{
    background:#fff0f0;
    color:#800;
    width:1024px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.good
{
    background:#eeffee;
    color:#008800; 
    width:1024px;        //same as above
    padding-left:10px;   //same as above
    margin-top:0;        //same as above
    margin-bottom:0;     //same as above
}
```

As you see out of 6 attributes, 4 are exactly same. So I thought of avoiding this duplication by writing a `.common` class and inherit them when defining the above classes, as shown below:

```
.common
{
    width:1024px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.good, .common    //inherit .commom
{
    background:#eeffee;
    color:#008800;
}
.bad, .common     //inherit .commom
{
    background:#fff0f0;
    color:#800;
}
```

But these change doesn't produce the same effect on the browser. I'm applying them on `<p>` tags and I see a gap between two consecutive `<p`> tags in the latter case. So it seems `margin-*` attributes are not inherited (or doesn't work the way it works in the first case).

All I'm looking for a way to avoid code-duplication. Is there any way to achieve that?

I'm not allowed to use [less](http://lesscss.org/) or any external tool or library. I just want my code to look shorter and concise in native CSS which I can put in the html file itself (no external .css file). I'm allowed to use javascript in the html itself (no jquery though).

Comment: You need to make use of both CSS Classes in HTML elements. Can you show  us your HTML code which uses these classes (good,bad & ugly :P)

Comment: You cannot inherit classes. Only properties can be inherited in CSS. And CSS has no class concept beyond class selectors.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Alright. I dont know CSS much, so I don't know what exactly `.good, .common { ... }` means in my code? Does it mean `.good` is supposed to include everything from `.common`?

Comment: `.good, .common { foobar }` means the same as `.good { foobar } .common { foobar }`. That is, the `foobar` declarations apply to elements in class `good` and to elements in class `common`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Ohh.. thanks. My misconception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bad, .common     //inherit .commom` doesn't do what you think, it sets styles to both, to `.bad` and `.common` elements.

If you have both classes on each element, you can use that.

```
<style>

.common {background: #fff0f0; color: #800; width: 1024px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
.good {background: #efe; color: #080; }

</style>
<p class="common bad">bad</p>
<p class="common good">good</p>
```

If you have just one class, `bad` and `good` on each element, use that

```
<style>

.bad, .good {background: #fff0f0; color: #800; width: 1024px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
.good {background: #efe; color: #080; }

</style>
<p class="bad">bad</p>
<p class="good">good</p>
```

Comment: The second one is good (pun intended) when you set more attributes in `.good` later on. That way I can define all the classes, having common attritubes once, then add more (differing) attributes later on.

Answer (score 4):

Using HTML you can inherit the other classes properties. You need to apply in your paragraph like this.

```
<p class="good common">Some Text</p>
<p class="bad common">Some new Text</p>
```

Need to update your CSS like below.

```
.common
{
width:1024px;
padding-left:10px;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
}
.good
{
background:#eeffee;
color:#008800;
}
.bad
{
background:#fff0f0;
color:#800;
}
```

**Explanation**:

First I will show you want your current structure is doing. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FeyLJ/. Now you can see the margin between two paragraph. So As of your thinking it will not inherit anything from CSS. So need to add the common class to your paragraph. Like

```
 <p class="good common">My Smaple Text</p>
 <p class="bad common">My another Simple Text</p>
```

After adding this see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FeyLJ/1/ what effect you got it? Now the margin issue gone. But did you notice that it produce one more issue. Yes both the paragraph now apply the same color background. Why? In CSS if you use the same class with same properties two times then it will take properties from the last defined place. In this case it is taken the same bad class background for both.

For your clarification move the order of the class like below.

```
.bad, .common 
{
background:#fff0f0;
color:#800;
} 

.good, .common 
{
background:#eeffee;
color:#008800;
}
```

This time it will apply the green color background instead of pink color. I hope you understand what order is doing here. So it will not inherit anything and why you need this? We can take out the common class. So Whereever we want, we can just use multiple classes like my answer above.

**[Here is the fiddle with my answer.](http://jsfiddle.net/FeyLJ/2/)**

Comment: Alright. That seems to be another way. But that doesn't explain what is wrong in my code? I dont know CSS much, so I don't know what exactly `.good, .common { ... }` means in my code? Does it mean `.good` is supposed to include everything from `.common`?

Comment: This is a good approach to the underlying problem, but it has nothing to do with inheritance. It just assigns two classes to some elements, so that the elements will match two different class selectors.

Comment: In your current structure, .bad, .common css class will overwrite the .good, .common class. This is not right.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: I didn't understand that. Please elaborate. What does *next to .bad, .common* means?

Comment: BTW, is there any difference between `class="good common"` and `class="common good"`? I mean what if I set the same attribute in both classes? Which value the html tag would pick?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: What "No not a problem"? I see a problem. If `good` has `color:#fff;` and `common` has `color:#000;`, which one would be used by the html? Would it be `#fff` or `#000`?

Comment: I have given my explanation briefly. check it out.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: I asked about the syntax you suggested which is this : `class="good common"`. So in this context, I'm asking what if I sett the same attribute in both classes? Which value would be used by html?

Comment: In the context 'class="good common"', it will take it from the common class. If you want it to take it from "good", you can change the order here or you can use "!important" in good class.

Answer (score 2):

you should write a BaseClass and refer it in your tags for E.G :

```
<p class="MyBaseClassForP ExtraClass AnotherExtraClass">text</p>
```